# Evaluate cells in a column and add rows based on the number of repeating responses in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of data that needs to have eight identical dates in a row, then increase to the next date (the data is monthly) and repeat that date eight times and so on.

Currently my column look like this:

```
201601
201601
201601
201601
201601
201601
201602
201602
201602
201602
201602
201603
201603
201603
201603
```

However I want it to be:

```
201601
201601 
201601 
201601 
201601 
201601 
201601
201601 
201602 
201602 
201602 
201602 
201602 
201602 
201602 
201602 
201603 
201603 
201603 
201603 
201603 
201603 
201603 
201603
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to handle this in Google sheets automatically or if I need to create script. I have knowledge of scripting but not much.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting afresh, say in A2 and copied down to suit:

```
=A1+if(mod(ROW(),8)=1,1,)
```

assuming A1 contains `201601` (text). This though only works up to month 12 of whatever year is in A1.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough in my question. I need to add a row when a date is missing since there is data in the next column that lines up with the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula as starting point:

`=ArrayFormula(CEILING(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&64))/8))`

It will give a sequence:

```
1
1
1
... ~ 8 times
2
2
2
...
...
8
8
8
8
```

The total values is 64 and step is 8 in the formula above.

---

## Next step

You have dates with step of 1 month. I suggest using:

- `text` to convert dates to format `YYYYMM`
- `eomonth` to add N months each iteration

The formula is:

`=ArrayFormula(TEXT(
  EOMONTH(date(2016,1,1),CEILING(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&500))/8)-1),"YYYYMM"))`

---

[More samples here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tjuoqWOy3QtozdWFYRePsBOEodCi_oThLSN_LVgrQbw/edit?usp=sharing)